# Maintaining a top 100 list in memory

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm making a live statistics system, that would maintain a list of most frequently accessed URL path (path only, parameters are stripped) in memory.

I've considered "max heap", but given that the URI pattern varies (that you can't predict new patterns), I can't use that data structure.

What I had in mind is that you need to record the count of each different URIs, e.g

```
www.google.com/pathA   5 times
www.google.com/pathB   3 times
...
```

So whenever a new URI pattern is discovered, you need to initialize an entry for it, otherwise you might just omit a critical URI.

You can't just really "keep a top 100 list".

Then it looks like impossible to implement without consuming lots of memory space.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean "*Top 100, **Ever***", or "*Top 100, since the last restart*", or "*Top 100, recently*"?  And if the last, then *how* recently do you mean?

Comment: “without consuming lots of memory space” Well, how much data do you have? How many URLs are you going to have? How many distinct paths?

Comment: "but given that the URI pattern varies (that you can't predict new patterns), I can't use that data structure" - could you explain what you meant by this? What is a pattern and why does it cause problems?

Comment: It seems to me that this is very similar to a OS page replacement problem where you only have limit memory so you can only keep a few pages in the memory and keep swapping in and out. If you want to be hundred percent sure that you have the top 100, and if you do not know how many urls there will be in total beforehand, you will have to keep count of all urls you have seen. In this case, if memory usage is critial, you might want to mimic the OS and store some counts elsewhere on disk. There are many strategies available like [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

Though it does not do exactly what you want I think [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) is what you need. It is a great data structure that has the property of keeping the most recently accessed elements and the most frequently accessed elements closer to the root.

If this will not do for you, use a heap and update the priority of elements when needed. You can not do that with the built in heap, but it is not hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure, you are listing top 100, you are right.

You can write some heuristic for this.
For example, you can record top 100 and last 100. New 100 would be second would be second list with urls that could become one of the top 100. It last 100 you can count as in top 100. If you access url which is not in top 100 and last 100, you would remove sth from last 100, i.e. the last accessed url.

It won't work if sb is accessing 101 urls one by one, but it's a good start.
You can think about different startegies which one should be removed and so on.

Example implementation:

```
top100 : list<(URL, count)>
last100: list<(URL, count, score)>

process(URL){
    if(URL in top100) incrementCount top100[URL];
    elif(URL in last100){
        incrementScore last100[URL];
        newCount := incrementCount last100[URL];
        if (newCount > top100.lowestCount)
            swap this URL between last100 and top100 
        }
    else{
        //perform check if should change sth in last100, i.e.:
        if(exists score=0 in last100)
            remove score0 from last100.
            put (URL, 1, 0) to last100;
        }
        else{
            decrement all score in last100
        }
     }
 }
```

Simple run for top/last 3 instead of 100.
Lets start in the middle, when:
top3 = [ (A, 10), (B, 4), (C, 3) ]
last3 = [ (E, 2, 0), (F, 1, 0), (G, 1, 0) ] (A..G are URLs)

G: last3 = [ (E, 2, 0), (G, 2, 1), (F, 1, 0) ] //inc G score, count

G: last3 = [ (E, 2, 0), (G, 3, 2), (F, 1, 0) ] //inc G score, count

H: last3 = [ (E, 2, 0), (G, 3, 2), (H, 1, 0) ] //put H instead of F

F: last3 = [ (E, 2, 0), (G, 3, 2), (F, 1, 0) ] //put F instead of G

G: top3 = [ (A, 10), (B, 4), (G, 4) ], [ (E, 2, 0), (C, 3, 2), (F, 1, 0) ] // swap G C

G: top3 = [ (A, 10), (B, 4), (G, 5) ] // inc G count

F: last3 = [ (E, 2, 0), (G, 3, 2), (F, 2, 1) ] //inc F score, count

E: last3 = [ (E, 3, 1), (G, 3, 2), (F, 2, 1) ] //inc E score, count

H: last3 = [ (E, 3, 0), (G, 3, 1), (F, 2, 0) ] //no el with score=0, dec all scores

H: last3 = [ (E, 3, 0), (G, 3, 1), (H, 1, 0) ] //put H instead of F

So F and G shows often, but unfortunately they prevent each other from keeping in last3, and getting to top3. In real word scenario with last/top100 (or more) it would be hard for situation like this to occur.

More complex strategy should manipulate scores and counts to improve deciding if new url should be put and if so, which url should be removed. You should prepare some sample data and create good quality strategy.

Comment: interesting, but still do not understand how say a potential url (urlA) which is not occurring periodically will move to the top100?

Comment: @zerocool It depends on moving to last100 strategy. With strategy from sample code it won't. Last100 is a list of candidates to top100. My strategy removes last used URL if we found new good candidate. I'll write simple run.

Comment: Some options worth considering: **(1)** Depreciate the values over time, thus newer URLs have a greater probability of making their way into the top 100 list (otherwise the list can be dominated by very old URLs that used to be popular). **(2)** Keep a few good candidates from the last 100 that didn't reach the top 100 (though probably not too necessary with (1)). **(3)** Keep more of the last ones than the top ones, say keep the last 200 instead.

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE: Sorry My solution if for most recently used and not for most popular. 
        I didn't read question properly before answering.**

I think what are you looking for is LRU cache or Least Recently Used cache 
We will extend LinkedHashMap with ordering mode 'true' to keep ordering.
And override 'removeEldestEntry' to return true when size exceeds max Entries.
In your case  maxEntries = 100.

Please look at (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html  ) for more details on LinkedHashMap

```
private class LruCache<A, B> extends LinkedHashMap<A, B> {
    private final int maxEntries;

    public LruCache(final int maxEntries) {
       /* Using constructor LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder) 
         Which Constructs an empty LinkedHashMap instance with the specified initial   
         capacity, load factor and ordering mode. */
        super(maxEntries + 1, 1.0f, true);
        this.maxEntries = maxEntries;
    }

   /* Returns true if this <code>LruCache</code> has more entries than the 
      maximum specified when it was created.*/
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(final Map.Entry<A, B> eldest) {
        return super.size() > maxEntries;
    }
}

Map<String, String> example = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LruCache<String, String>(CACHE_SIZE));
```

Comment: How exactly is this going to help? Also, your code is very confusing, since `removeEldestEntry()` doesn't use its parameter and also doesn't actually remove anything.

Comment: Here we are overriding LinkedHashMap::removeEldestEntry. This functions Returns true if this map should remove its eldest entry.  You can look at "LinkedHashMap" for more details. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html ) . Please do some webSearch before down voting an answer.

Comment: Whoever downvoted was right.. I don't see how this solves anything.

Comment: @ShaktiMalik OK, I didn't notice the `@Override`. But that still doesn't explain what does this have to do with the question.

Comment: LRU is for most **recent**, not most **popular**. Thus this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sorry Dukeling is correct. I think i didn't read the question properly.